# Share clipboard between 3 computers with RDP & VMWare (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vmware-player, clipboard

From my windows10 workstation 'Oren-PC' i connect with RDP to another windows10 machine 'devServer'.

On 'devServer' machine I have VMWare installed with a Ubuntu 14.04 OS machine (VMWare tools installed).

The clipboard between the 'devServer' and ubuntu is shared, as well as between 'Oren-PC' and 'devServer'.

Is it possible to share the clipboard between 'Oren-PC' and the ubuntu machine (2 hops) ?
So far I haven't been able to copy/paste anything.

Comment: Do you need the remote-viewing capability or would just the control and copypaste functionality work? Like do you have both displays next to each other or can you not easily do that?

Comment: I have remote-viewing capability. I have both displays. I just can't copy/paste text/files from my workstation to the virtual machine since it's on another PC

Comment: If you have both displays, I'd look at Synergy. http://synergy-project.org/

Comment: In a similar situation, so far the best I can do is copy something on "Ubuntu", paste it into "devServer", copy it AGAIN there, and finally paste it into Oren-PC. This also works in the opposite direction (so copy from Oren-PC, go via devDerver and paste to Ubuntu.) However, it is very cumbersome and annoying. And I suspect that all three of the "machines" being Windows in my case may have made a difference.